# How to align textFields at the bottom of a stetched textField?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm having a problem using Jasper report.

In my report I'm trying to align textFields like:

```
${name}                      ${field1}
${age}                       ${field2}
${address}                   ${field3}
```

The textField `${name}` is able to `stretchWithOverflow` causing it to break alignment with `${field1}`.

If the textField `${name}` stretches I would like to get a result where `${field1}` aligns with the last line on that `${name}` is stretched to.

```
${name}                      
${name}(stretched)           ${field1}
${age}                       ${field2}
${address}                   ${field3}
```

I've read many forums but could not find a solution.

Comment: Hi I posted an answer and edit the question (title as question and some minor grammar).... Maybe you should consider to change horizontally in title to vertically or bottom (the title seems strange...), but can't edit to much since I do not wan't to change your original without consulting you (the post is yours : )

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! The title was indeed strange, i changed it to represent the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve this by using the `positionType="FixRelativeToBottom"` attribute

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="csvTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="601103bc-66ab-45a5-8422-ccb6f3e02ec2">
    queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="age" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="adress" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="60" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="bf6b550c-f37d-4e10-b8dd-1d91c4e6905a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="20" width="100" height="20" uuid="cbcc18ce-a1c8-4659-b30e-c1a360392b0a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="40" width="100" height="20" uuid="ffda046d-87cc-4f51-8568-99c19a54ed7e"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{adress}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="2110cf81-a71d-45c0-9bd9-d26d69167860"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="100" y="20" width="100" height="20" uuid="2c7fd4ec-324f-4c03-9b13-c3e1bb83d6ad"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="100" y="40" width="100" height="20" uuid="6371e8da-43d8-43e6-86a3-65bedd87f030"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="1" uuid="719e26b2-88ef-4558-a6d6-2c0589e04638"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Example data:**

```
+-----------------------------+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|            name             | age |   adress   |   field1    |   field2    |   field3    |
+-----------------------------+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Very long name that stretch |  12 | Selvarella | field1Value | field2Value | field3Value |
| Shorty                      |  13 | New York   | field1Value | field2Value | field3Value |
+-----------------------------+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

**NOTE**: It can get more complex if you have multiple fields that stretch in same detail band, in these cases you may need to use subreport to get correct layout.

For more info see [Jasper Report stretch sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/stretch/)